# Do you repair holes/imperfections in travertine tiles before or after sealing them

Tags: sealer, travertine

I am doing a backsplash project with 12x12 mosaic travertine tile on mesh

Some of the 2x2 tiles have holes and imperfections which I hope to fill with grout which is the same color as the tile

I am planning to seal the tiles before I adhere them to the walls.............

My question is if the tile is sealed with 511 impregnator sealer prior to adhering to the wall will the grout adhere to the holes?

Should I fill in the holes before I seal the tiles?

Comment: If you seal the tiles prior to installing them, I’d be concerned that they may not adhere to the wall. Why not seal everything after installation?

Comment: My advice s to install then wipe with sealer not saturating then fill holes and grout lines this helps keep grit from bonding  to surface     After dry seal it all well

Answer (score 0):

Seal after the install. Some material does come pre-sealed but I have only seen it sealed by the professionals after installation